# merging two lists of tuples in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

let's assume these are my lists:

```
oracle_files = [
    (1, "__init__.py"),
    (2, "price_calc.py"),
    (3, "lang.py")]
predicted_files = [
    (5, ["random.py","price_calc.py"]),
    (2, ["__init__.py","price_calc.py"]),
    (1, ["lang.py","__init__.py"])]
```

first list is a list of tuples where i have an identifier and a string per each.
second one is a list of tuples of integers and list of strings

my intention is to create a third list that intersects these two ones by ID (the integer)

and the output should look like this:

```
result = [(2, "price_calc.py", ["__init__.py","price_calc.py"]), 
          (1, "__init__.py", ["lang.py","__init__.py"])]
```

do you know a way to reach this output? because i'm not getting it right.

Comment: Now you can ask a question about the problem you have encountered with your code.

Comment: I would start by finding a way to get the identifiers that are common between the two lists.

Comment: I would build a dictionary with the identifier as a key, and when done, pull the contents with `dct.items()`.

Comment: The identifiers and integers are guaranteed to be unique, right?

Comment: @wjandrea yes exactly! thanks to everybody who answered anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using dict:

```py
oracle_files = [(1, "__init__.py"), (2, "price_calc.py"), (3, "lang.py")]
predicted_files = [(5, ["random.py","price_calc.py"]), (2, ["__init__.py","price_calc.py"]), (1, ["lang.py","__init__.py"])]

dct1 = dict(oracle_files)
dct2 = dict(predicted_files)

result = [(k, dct1[k], dct2[k]) for k in dct1.keys() & dct2.keys()]
print(result) # [(1, '__init__.py', ['lang.py', '__init__.py']), (2, 'price_calc.py', ['__init__.py', 'price_calc.py'])]
```

This uses a convenient fact that the dict keys obtained from `dict.keys()` behave like a set.

> Keys views are set-like since their entries are unique and hashable. [...] For set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base class collections.abc.Set are available (for example, `==`, `<`, or `^`).
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want.

```
oracle_files = [(1, "__init__.py"), (2, "price_calc.py"), (3, "lang.py")]
predicted_files = [(5, ["random.py","price_calc.py"]), (2, ["__init__.py","price_calc.py"]), (1, ["lang.py","__init__.py"])]

dct = dict(oracle_files)
for k,v in predicted_files:
    if k in dct:
        dct[k] = (dct[k], v)
print(dct)

outlist = [(k,)+v for k,v in dct.items() if isinstance(v,tuple)]
print(outlist)
```

Output:

```
{1: ('__init__.py', ['lang.py', '__init__.py']), 2: ('price_calc.py', ['__init__.py', 'price_calc.py']), 3: 'lang.py'}
[(1, '__init__.py', ['lang.py', '__init__.py']), (2, 'price_calc.py', ['__init__.py', 'price_calc.py'])]
```